# How to Select dates when i sold nothing?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-analysis

Assume i have a table of item_sold from 01-01-2020 to 01-01-2023 with columns product_id, product_name, quantity and date.

I want to get all the dates when i sold nothing.
I am using Postgresql, please help me in this problem.

I tried withclaue and many other things but they didn't worked.

Comment: How are you checking the dates, do you have all dates in the table and 0 for the qty?

Comment: i mean i have  stored all the sold products with the selling date in 2020-2021, and i want the dates when i sold nothing, my desired dates are not in my column but in the time range 2020-2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of calendar table containing all dates which you potentially want to report.  Assuming the date range be the entire years of 2020 through 2023 inclusive, we can try the following left anti-join approach:

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT ('2020-01-01'::date + s.a) AS dt
    FROM generate_series(0, 365*4) AS s(a)
)

SELECT d.dt
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t.item_sold = d.dt
WHERE t.item_sold IS NULL
ORDER BY d.dt;
```